# Navigation bar doesn't fit the screen when zooming out

Tags: html, css

i just started to code html and css. I created a  to make a navigation bar on top of my landing page but the problem is, the size of navbar doesnt fit into page when i zoom out, its getting smaller everytime i zoom out. How can i make it fit with keep everthing in body section centered?[I zoomed out to %75 in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laqcx.png)

Here is my code for HTML and CSS

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
  padding: 0px;
  max-width: 1920px;
  margin: auto;

}

.navigation-bar {
  height: 70px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-bar"> 
    <div class="logo">Gezy</div>
    <div class="button-container">
        <div class="join-now"><button>Join Now</button></div>
        <div class="log-in"><button>Log In</button></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<body>` element is constraining it, because you've set a maximum width:

```
max-width: 1920px;
```

Remove that and the constraint goes away.

Comment: Thanks, yes it fix it but now the content under the navbar getting closer to the left side of the page when i zoom out, so how can i fix that? Can i fix both of them at the same time?

Comment: @FurkanGüler: What "content under the navbar" are you referring to?  The question asked has no such content.

Comment: I centered some picture, header and button with div elements on the center of the page but its getting closer to the left side of the page when i zoom out.

Comment: @FurkanGüler: If you have some other code which produces some other problem then you are encouraged to debug and correct that code.  If you encounter a specific problem during that attempt, this community can help with that.  When you ask a new question about that problem, please include a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and indicate specifically what you are trying to solve.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your navigation bar remains fixed in size even when zooming out and everything in the body is centered, you can use a combination of relative and absolute positioning. Here's an updated version of your code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body, html {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            max-width: 1920px;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .navigation-bar {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            height: 70px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding: 0 20px;
            background-color: #fff; /* Add a background color to make it visible */
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 1000; /* Ensure the navigation bar is on top of other elements */
        }

        .logo {
            font-size: 1.5em;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .button-container {
            display: flex;
            gap: 10px;
        }

        .join-now button, .log-in button {
            padding: 8px 16px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navigation-bar"> 
        <div class="logo">Gezy</div>
        <div class="button-container">
            <div class="join-now"><button>Join Now</button></div>
            <div class="log-in"><button>Log In</button></div>
        </div> 
    </div>

    <!-- Your main content goes here -->

</body>
</html>
```

- Use position: fixed; for the navigation bar to keep it fixed at the top.
- Set top, left, right, and width to ensure it spans the full width.
  justify-content: space-between; in .navigation-bar to push the logo to the left and the buttons to the right.
- Added some basic styles to the logo and buttons for better visibility.